# Telerik MVC Scheduler RecurranceID value missing

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-scheduler

When user 'Breaks' a reoccurring appointment, I receive the create event for the newly modified appointment plus the change of the existing series to exclude the appointment.
In the 'create' event I never see the RecurrenceID value at the controller, it's always 'nothing'.

Checking the Network I spotted this being sent to the controller. It seems the client is sending an additional 'recurrenceid' , all lowercase with the actual value I need.. but this never makes it.

[image: Form Post data]

Note I am using a custom event editor , however I get the same result using the standard editor.

My Scheduler looks like this

```
  With Html.Kendo().Scheduler(Of ExceptionViewModel)() _
            .Name("scheduler") _
            .Date(Now()) _
            .StartTime(New DateTime(2016, 6, 13, 0, 0, 0))
            ' .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
            .WorkDayStart(7, 0, 0)
            .ShowWorkHours(False)
            .WorkDayEnd(19, 0, 0)
            .EventTemplateId("Event-template")
            .Height(700)
            .Width(1300)
            .Messages(Sub(mess)
                          mess.Editor(Sub(edit)
                                          edit.EditorTitle("Exception")
                                      End Sub)
                      End Sub)
            .WorkWeekStart(1)
            .WorkWeekEnd(5)
            .Editable(Sub(edit)
                          edit.TemplateId("customEditorTemplate")
                      End Sub)
            .Events(Function(events) events.DataBound("shadeoutofhours"))
            .Views(Sub(views)
                       views.DayView()
                       views.WeekView()
                       views.MonthView()
                       views.TimelineView()
                       views.AgendaView()
                   End Sub)

            .DataSource(Function(d) d.Model(Sub(m)
                                                m.Id(Function(f) f.TaskID)
                                            End Sub) _
            .Read("read", "Tasks") _
            .Create("create", "Tasks") _
            .Destroy("destroy", "Tasks") _
            .Update("update", "Tasks"))
            .Render()
        End With
```

My version is 2015.3.1111.545 Dev ( not sure what the Dev means!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it , answering in case it helps someone.

I had to map the RecurrenceID in the Model and now it's working as it should be :)

```
    .DataSource(Function(d) d.Model(Sub(m)
                                        m.Id(Function(f) f.TaskID)
                                        m.RecurrenceId(Function(f) f.RecurrenceID)
                                    End Sub) _
```